# upload local image file to aws s3 without input field

Tags: reactjs, image, pdf, amazon-s3, file-upload

I'm making a react app where I let the user upload a pdf file and then I convert the pdf file to a jpg file, store it locally then upload it to aws s3. However currently, when I upload the jpg file to aws s3 the file is not uploaded as an image file. I want to upload a local image file to aws s3 without having to use `<input type="file" />`

I tried this using `fs.readFile()` with `s3.upload()` but the file that is uploaded is not an image file. I also tried using `multer-s3` but this requires the user to manually select the image file using a `<input type="file" />`, which I want to avoid.

Here is how I'm uploading the jpg file:

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("fs");
const convertPdf = require("pdf-poppler");
const s3 =  new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: "<key>",
  secretAccessKey: "<secret>",
  Bucket: "<bucketName>"
});
const storage = multer.diskStorage({ 
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname + "/uploads/"));
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    // let pdfName = "samplePDF";
    // req.body.file = pdfName;
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});  //SAVING PDF TO DISK STORAGE

router.post("/pdf", upload.single("pdf"),(req, res, next) => {
  const uploadPath = req.file.path;
  var imagePath = req.file.destination + req.file.originalname.slice(0, -4) + "-1.jpg";
  let opts = {
    format: "jpg",
    out_dir: req.file.destination,
    out_prefix: path.basename(req.file.path).slice(0, -4),
    page: null
  }
  //CONVERTING PDF TO JPG
  convertPdf.convert(uploadPath, opts).then(() => 
  {
     fs.readFile(imagePath, (err, data) => { 
      if (err) throw err;// UPLOADING FILE BUT NOT IN IMAGE FORMAT
      const params = {
         Bucket: "<bucketName>",
         Key: path.basename(imagePath),
         Body: data 
       };
      s3.upload(params, (s3Error, data) => {
        if (s3Error) throw s3Error;
        console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`);
        res.json({
          image: data.key,
          location: data.Location
        });
      });
     });
    });
  });
```

I expected an image file to be uploaded but not the uploaded file is not an image file which is the problem. Is there any way to upload a local image file to aws s3 without requiring the use of an input field?

**EDIT:** turns out aws s3 makes the uploaded file private by default which is why the file could not be read, issue is resolved when I make the file public.

Comment: So what is the uploaded file? What is the extension? Is the contents as expected? If not what is it?

Comment: the file is of  .jpg extension but it says the contents are damaged whenever I try to download the file from the s3 bucket so I assume it's not an image file

Comment: Open it in a text editor. What do you see?

Comment: Never mind the uploaded file is an image file, turns out s3 blocks the read access for the file by default , as soon I enabled read access the image shows as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uploaded file was an image file, it just didn't have the right permissions. I added the `ACL: "public-read"` param and now the file displays as expected.
Updated code:

```
  fs.readFile(imagePath, (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const params = {
        Bucket: "flyingfishcattle",
        Key: path.basename(imagePath),
        Body: data,
        ACL: "public-read" 
      };
      s3.upload(params, (s3Error, data) => {
        if (s3Error) throw s3Error;
        console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`);
        res.json({
          image: data.key,
          location: data.Location
        });
      });
    });
```